# query on list property in app engine java

Tags: java, list, google-app-engine

I understand that when you do use the IN operator in a query like the following, that it causes multiple queries:

```
select * from A where a IN (1,2,3)
```

On the other hand, how does appengine handle query where we are looking for a single value in a list property?

```
select * from B where someListProp IN 1
```

What does this do behind the scenes? does it cause multiple queries like the other?

Answer (score 0):

1. This will create three queries and combine results. The upside is that this happens on database server(s) so there is only roundtrip.
2. No, this creates one query.